# MongoDB pymongo indexing gives error for key word searching

Tags: python, mongodb, keyword-search

I am using Mac and trying to use MongoDB 3.0 indexing to search for key words. Using Python, I have created the index successfully with ensure_index() or create_index()
Here's my code for creating the index, it works well:

```
import json
import pymongo
from bson import json_util
mbox.create_index([('$**', 'text')], name = 'TextIndex', type = 'text')
```

However, when I tried to search for key word in both MongoDB and pymongo client, none of them works and they all give me similar errors, saying

**"pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('text', 'mbox'), ('search', 'raptor'), ('limit', 1)]) on namespace enron.$cmd failed: no such command: 'text', bad cmd: '{ text: "mbox", search: "raptor", limit: 1 }'"**

Here's the key word search code:

```
print json.dumps(db.command("text", "mbox", search = "raptor", limit = 1),
                 indent = 1,
                 default = json_util.default
                 )
```

Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you enable text search on your DB?

Comment: Yes, I did, I used "mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true", but still got the error... @Jefe